# Boost.log: No output in the console or in the output file respectively

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, eclipse-cdt, boost-log

I've downloaded and compiled successfully the boost.log sources from svn under Windows 7 using mingw-4.7. 
IDE: eclipse-juno with CDT.

The compilation string for the entire boost-sources (including boost.log in the appropriate folders) was:

**"bjam --build-type=complete mc-compiler=windmc"**

As output I've received a "**libboost_log-mgw47-1_51" and "libboost_log_setup-mgw47-mt-1_51**".

However I see no output when running the trivial sample code from the boost.log documentation below.

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp> 
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp> 
#include <boost/log/utility/init/to_console.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost::log; 

int main(int argc, 
const char* argv[]) {

init_log_to_file();

BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message"; 
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message"; 
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

return 0; 
}
```

The same applies for the following code-snipped:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp> 
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp> 
#include <boost/log/utility/init/to_console.hpp> 
#include <boost/log/utility/init/to_file.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace boost::log; 

int main(int argc, 
const char* argv[]) {

init_log_to_file("sample.log");

BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message"; 
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message"; 
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

return 0; 
}
```

Could someone give me a hint why I see nothing on the console?

thanks a lot in advance,

Degoah

Comment: It's not a part of boost yet. Try asking here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log/forums/forum/710022

Comment: I've already placed an question on sourceforge.net! Indeed, it's still not a part of boost, but it's possible to download the source and lib separately and to reference it. And many developers have already test and used it. So, can anybody help me? Greetings

Comment: if the library author could not, I doubt anyone else will be able :(.

Comment: Please follow the discussion here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log/forums/forum/710021/topic/6078286